# How can I close the client-side JavaScript 'Hub' connection in SignalR?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

But there is no hint how to close the Websocket connection via the `HubConnection` class in `signalr.js`-file. The file is V1.0.4.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648457/signalr-close-connection) does not resolve my problem because I am using the microsofts javascript-library.

Here ist the code:

```
var lHubConnection = null;

var Init = function () {

    // create instance
    lHubConnection = new signalR.lHubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

    // receive message
    lHubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (pMessage) {

        // show message
        console.log(JSON.parse(pMessage));
    });

    // [...]
};

// close websocket connection
var CloseConnection = function(){

    if (lHubConnection !== null && lHubConnection.connection.connectionState === 1) {   
        // lHubConnection.invoke("?"); ???
    }
};
```

Here is an console output of the lHubConnection instance:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `HubConnection.StopAsync`? According to MS docs, thats how you close the hub connection.

Comment: There is no *.StopAsync() method. Can you please post the link of the MS docs where you have seen that?

Comment: Ah that method may not be available in the JavaScript version, I'm not 100% sure. [Here is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnection.stopasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: @Vincent P: That is the serverside c# code. I am looking for the clientside js-code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Microsoft the JavaScript client contains a stop function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40aspnet/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#stop

In addition, you can find the .stop()-Method in the prototype of the framework:

[image: signalrR prototype]